# Demonstrate equality (cotangent)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Any hint to demonstrate that the function

$$
C(z) = \pi\cot \pi z
$$

satisfies

$$
2F(2z) = F(z) + F(z + \frac{1}{2}),
$$
please?

Thanks.

Comment: So you have to show that $2C(2z) = C(z) + C(z+\frac{1}{2})$. Substitute in the definition of $C(z)$ and then try to use trig identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
C(z) +C(z+{1/2})= \pi\Big(\cot (\pi z)+\cot( {\pi z+{\pi/2}})\Big) =\pi\Big(\cot (\pi z)-\tan( \pi z)\Big)
$$
$$ = \pi{\cos^2 (\pi z)-\sin^2( \pi z)\over \cos (\pi z)\sin( \pi z)} =\pi {2\cos(2\pi z)\over \sin(2\pi z)} = 2C(2z)
$$